# Class diagram for user actions depending on roles

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I'm a beginner in UML, I have a PHP app where there is an admins area and users area. a user can have either `admin` role, `user` role or both.
In the user interface we can submit a `salary_request` for a salary advance, and then in the admin panel we can either `accept` or `deny` the `salary_request`s and that will simply change the `status` for the actual `salary_request`.

The Database is as follow :

- `users` table : id, email, password, first_name, last_name
- `roles` table : id, name
- `user_role` : user_id, role_id (relation table between `users` and `roles`)
- `salary_requests`: id, amount, date, requested_by, validated_by, status

so the Classes are :

- `User`
- `Role`
- `SalaryRequest`
- and `Status` enum

I don't know how to add these relations/rules in the Class diagram :

- `User` can have one or multiple roles
- if the `User` is a simple user, he can only submit `SalaryRequests`
- if the `User` is an admin, he can accept or deny the `SalaryRequest`
- if the `User` has both roles `admin` & `user` he can add `SalaryRequests` and also accept or deny them.

All I could figure out is this Class diagram which is incomplete and I'm not sure if it's correct so far :

[image: Class Diagram]

Comment: From what I see there is no issue here. So what is yours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> User can have one or multiple roles

Multiplicities can be applied to the association between User and Role to identify this. In UML, multiplicities are written in text at each end of the association, either in a list of absolute values or as a range in the form "Lower .. Upper", with '*' being a wildcard meaning "any".

For example:

- 0 .. * which means zero or many.
- 1 .. * which means one or many.
- 1, 2 which means one or two only.
- 1 which means exactly one.

Thus the association between User and Role could have a multiplicity of '1' (exactly one) on the User end and '1..*' (one or many) at the Role end.

However, I suspect that a Role can have more than one User fulfil it, so I suspect that the relationship is actually User '0..*' to Role '1..*'. I.e. a User must have 1 or more Roles, and a Role can have zero or more Users.

> if the User is a simple user, he can only submit SalaryRequests if the
>   User is an admin, he can accept or deny the SalaryRequest if the User
>   has both roles admin & user he can add SalaryRequests and also accept
>   or deny them.

This is a little harder explain how to express, as the answer depends on what you're trying to explain and why.

Class diagrams express aspects of the *structure* of your code rather than its behaviour, and what you are trying to express here is more *behavioural*.

The association between User and SalaryRequest in your diagram is already broad enough to cover all of the rules that you have identified above, so purely from a class-design perspective you could leave it as it is and explain the behavioural rules of the system in some other way (e.g. use Use Cases or an Activity Diagram to explain it instead).

However, if you think that the rules are strong enough that you need to encode them in the *structure* of the classes, then you would have to start deriving out different sub-types or composites in the classes that encapsulate the behaviour you want and then use associations between those to cast the rules in stone in the structure. But, a word of caution: I'm not sure you actually want to do this structurally, as the cost of changing structure is generally higher and more far-reaching than in changing behaviour.

**Edit Following Comments Below**

This is a possible way in which you can try and capture the behavioural rules in the structure of the classes. This example uses interfaces and operations (i.e. structural elements that encapsulate behaviour) to do that. You will notice that the behaviour is attached to the *Role* rather than the *User*. The User *in their capacity fulfilling a Role* performs these behaviours -- i.e. it's the Role that has the rights, not the User per se. At least that's my logic :-).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. So for the second point, you are saying that in the Class Diagram I can make a super-class called `AbstractUser` for example, and two sub-classes called `User` & `Admin`, then each one will have a specific association with `SalaryRequest` class to describe it more? And it's not necessary to have this same structure in my actual code, so I'll just leave one `User` class in the code to make it simple?

Comment: Yes, that would be one way, but even still it is hard to explain the rules you want. The associations would have to have constraints applied to them to express the rules which is a bit clunky. Instead you could use interfaces, for example, "RequestApprover" and "RequestMaker" through which the User or Role -- or a sub-type of one of these such as you describe in your comment -- interacts with the SalaryRequest. This way the business logic of Approve/Reject and Make can be expressed in the structure of the classes. I'll edit the answer to provide this example.

Comment: Oh I got it! Thank you for the detailed answer, I appreciate it.